# Find years of experience in a string using regexs in Python

Tags: python, regex

How can I write a regex which searches for following in Python:

```
10+ years
10 years
1 year
10-15 years
```

So far, I have used this, but its not providing result for all of them.

```
re_expression = '(\d+).(years|year|Year|Years)'
    exp_temp = re.search(re_expression.decode('utf-8'),description)
    experience_1=''
    if exp_temp:
        experience_1 = exp_temp.groups()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
r'(\d+(?:-\d+)?\+?)\s*(years?)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KwngR1/2). Compile with `re.I` flag to enable case insensitive matching.

**Details**

- `(\d+(?:-\d+)?\+?)` - Group 1:

  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `(?:-\d+)?` - an optional group matching `-` and then 1+ digits
  - `\+?` - an optional `+` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(years?)` - Group 2: `year` or `years`

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/czLZqn):

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r"(\d+(?:-\d+)?\+?)\s*(years?)", re.I)
strs = ["10+ years", "10 years", "1 year", "10-15 years"] 
for description in strs:
    exp_temp = rx.search(description)
    if exp_temp:
        print(exp_temp.groups())
```

Output:

```
('10+', 'years')
('10', 'years')
('1', 'year')
('10-15', 'years')
```

Comment: To be precise, the regex should be `\d+(?:\+|-\d+)?\s+years?\b` otherwise your regex also matches `10-15+ years` which shouldn't match. After the primary number, it should be either `+` or `-\d+`

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I deliberately used what I used. There is no requirement to avoid matching `10-15+ years`.

Comment: Going by your logic, even `[\w +-]+` would suffice :) Logically I think you will agree, people generally express age as `10+` or `25+` or range like `10-15` or `25-30` but they never express age like `10-15+` which doesn't look right. At least I've never seen anyone express age like that :) And I agree you must have deliberately done that.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi `[\w +-]+` is not equal to `\d+(?:-\d+)?\+?`. I do not want to match a streak of mere spaces or plus symbols. If OP wants to precise the requirements, the solution can be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Agreed Wiktor :) Was just pulling your leg. Hope you don't mind :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What if we also have another case like "(2) years". Then what will we need to modify? I am sorry, I am very bad at regex.

Comment: @Ella It can look like `r"((?:\(\d+\)|\d+)(?:-\d+)?\+?)\s*(years?)"`

Comment: Great, thank you for helping. And this is for both "Years" and "years" ? I mean with capital and small y?

Comment: @Ella If you use `re.I`, it will match `year` or `years` in a case insensitive way. You may add `(?i)` to the pattern (`r"(?i)((?:\(\d+\)|\d+)(?:-\d+)?\+?)\s*(years?)"`) if you do not want to mess with flags.

Answer (score 3):

## `([\d+-]+)\s+(years?)`

---

```
import re

x ="""
123 10+ years some text
some text 99 10 years ssss
text 1 year and more text
some text 10-15 years some text
"""

result = re.findall(r"([\d+-]+)\s+(years?)", x, re.IGNORECASE)
print(result)
```

---

```
[('10+', 'years'), ('10', 'years'), ('1', 'year'), ('10-15', 'years')]
```

---

[Python Demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/Qis)

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oGea3A/2)

---

Regex Explanation:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match your values and don't need the capturing groups, you might use:

`\b(?:\d+-\d+ [yY]ears|[02-9] [Yy]ears|1 [Yy]ear|[1-9]\d+\+? [Yy]ears)\b`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uX9oE8/1)

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\d+-\d+ [yY]ears` Match format 10-15 years
  - `|` Or
  - `[02-9] [Yy]ears` Match format 0 or 2-9 years
  - `|` Or
  - `1 [Yy]ear` Match format 1 year
  - `|` Or
  - `[1-9]\d+\+? [Yy]ears` Match format 10+ years
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `\b` Word boundary

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/OujLMo)